# Relation на себя, через смежную модель

Tags: yii2

Есть таблица пользователей

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`) VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`) VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO `user` (`user_id`) VALUES (3);
```

И таблица хранящая пользователей, которые подписаны на других пользователей)

```
CREATE TABLE `user_subscriber` (
    `user_subscriber_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `subscriber_id` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_subscriber_id`),
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
    INDEX `subscriber_id` (`subscriber_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `fk-user_subscriber-user` FOREIGN KEY (`subscriber_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `fk-user_subscriber-user-self` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_unicode_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=4;

INSERT INTO `user_subscriber` (`user_id`, `subscriber_id`) VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO `user_subscriber` (`user_id`, `subscriber_id`) VALUES (1, 3);
INSERT INTO `user_subscriber` (`user_id`, `subscriber_id`) VALUES (3, 2);
INSERT INTO `user_subscriber` (`user_id`, `subscriber_id`) VALUES (3, 1);
```

где **user_id** - на кого подписаны

**subscriber_id** - кто подписан

К примеру 1-й пользователь имеет два подписчика 2-го и 3-го пользователей, и сам в свою очередь подписан на 3-го пользователя

Пробую сделать релейшен для пользователя

```
class User extends ActiveRecord {
    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getUserSubscribers() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserSubscriber::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getSubscribers() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id', 'subscriber_id'])
            ->via('userSubscribers');
    }
}
```

Ну и вытянуть его

```
//Тут все подтянулось
$userSubscribers = $model->userSubscribers;

//А вот тут ловлю ошибку
$subscribers = $model->subscribers;
```

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'where
>   clause' The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE (`0`,
>   `1`) IN ((1, 2), (1, 3))

Почему-то ломается запрос. Возможно из-за ссылки на самого себя.

Comment: может надо сделать один рилейшн? public function getUserSubscribers() { return $this->hasMany(static::className(), ['user_id' => 'subscriber_id'])->viaTable(UserSubscriber::tableName(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
    }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее должно получиться что то вроде

```php
/**
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property User[] $subscribers
 * @property UserSubscriber[] $userSubscribers
 */
class User extends ActiveRecord {
    public function getUserSubscribers() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserSubscriber::className(), ["user_id" => "user_id"]);
    }

    public function getSubscribers() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::className(), ["user_id" => "user_id"])->viaTable(UserSubscriber::tableName(), ['subscriber_id' => 'user_id']);
    }
}

/**
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property integer $subscriber_id
 * @property User[] $user
 * @property User[] $subscriber
 */
class UserSubscriber extends ActiveRecord {
    public function getUser() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'user_id']);
    }
    public function getSubscriber() {
        return $this->hasOne(User::className(), ['user_id' => 'subscriber_id']);
    }
}
```

Так же советую почитать на тему **inverseOf** например [тут](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html)

Comment: Cпасибо, натолкнуло на мою ошибку. Можно и через **via**, просто по невнимательности указал в релейшене `['user_id', 'subscriber_id']` вместо  `['user_id' => 'subscriber_id']`